# Does the movement of holes in semiconductors cause friction?

Tags: electricity, friction

Sometimes physics looks at the movement of holes, or the absence of electrons, as if the holes were actually particles. Movement of electrons in materials often cause friction and give off some form of electromagnetic radiation - such as heat or light. Does the movement of holes in materials have a similar effect?

Comment: Holes are the absence of electrons in valence band states. Their movement is actually the movement of the  valence electrons. Hence, they scatter just like electrons do, resulting in resistance and conversion of hole energy to heat.

Answer (score 1):

In a conventional conductor energy is lost mainly when electrons scatter off the crystal lattice and transfer some of their kinetic energy into lattice vibrations. These lattice vibrations are of course just heat so the kinetic energy of the electrons is lost as heat.

Although we talk about holes moving in for example a $p$ type semiconductor it is actually the electrons that are moving, and just as with a conventional conductor those electrons will scatter off the lattice and lose energy as heat.

I'm not sure I would use the term *friction* to describe this as friction is a specific mechanical process. The usual term is [resistance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrical_resistance_and_conductance).